# Coding style in javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I am interested in your opinion regarding the following code:

```
            this.skipAdmCharge = function (tot) {
                if (FR.rynTag.hasOwnProperty('prodfix')) {
                    var prodfix = FR.rynTag.prodfix;
                    for (var prop in prodfix) {
                        if (prodfix.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                            if (prodfix[prop].key === 'ADM') {
                                tot.amt -= prodfix[prop].price * prodfix[prop].quantity
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and this one below:

```
            this.skipAdmCharge = function (tot) {
                var prodfix = FR.rynTag.prodfix;
                if (prodfix) {
                    for (var prop in prodfix)
                        if (prop && (prop.key === 'ADM'))
                           tot.amt -= prop.price * prop.quantity
                }
            }
```

Which one do you consider to be better? And if so, why?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a matter of "style"; it's a matter of correctness for a given problem in a given context. Without knowing the context it's not possible to give an answer.

Comment: As they don't do the same, the example is a little misleading

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because commentary about working programs is appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Pointy I think OP refers to the lack of braces (not sure)

Comment: @dystroy maybe, but the most prominent difference (to me) is the lack of `.hasOwnProperty()` tests in the second code sample.

Comment: @Point I agree it is the `hasOwnProperty()` that is the difference.  While the two codes are not the same, I think the 2nd style is more clear, and probably what the OP intends to accomplish.

Comment: Always use braces. Not using them is prone error

Comment: I thought this question was "primarly opinion based" but it turns out it's mainly "unclear"

Comment: I think this question is OK, the OP just want to know which one is better

Comment: Always use braces to delimit blocks. The additional typing is negligeable compared to the time spent tracking errors upon a single incidence of  adding a code line to the for loop / else branch without thinking of the missing block delimiters.

Answer (score -1):

Both have few unwanted checks..

Example in case of first one `if (prodfix.hasOwnProperty(prop))` is not necessary
In case of second one,  `if (prop &&` not necessary.

```
 this.skipAdmCharge = function (tot) {
    try {
        var prodfix = FR.rynTag.prodfix;
        if (prodfix) {
            for (var prop in prodfix)
                if (prop.key === 'ADM'))
                    tot.amt -= prop.price * prop.quantity
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("failed to calculate total amount in skipAdmCharge" + e.message);
    }
}
```

PS:I am also new to JavaScript!